# Titanium appcelerator - is there any way to use custom font in picker?

Tags: titanium

my question is how can I use custom font in my picker...
Seems like I can't use the fontFamily property in any of those:

Ti.UI.createPicker / Ti.UI.createPickerColumn / Ti.UI.createPickerRow ...

So I thought about adding label or view to the picker...but with no success...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, it's not available in the current implementation of Titanium mobile.
The only option would be making a custom widget for now.

Comment: Thnaks for the bad news, mate :-)